# I got SQLITE_IOERR in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I developed an app in which I am using sqlite3 as a database.

Sometimes I got SQLITE_IOERR i.e 10, and because of this db cannot return any value.

But if I launch app again after terminating from background, it works fine then.

How to SOLVE this error, any help?

Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to solve your error if you do not post the relevant code... Please be selective and post only what you think is relevant to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SQLITE_IOERR

This value is returned if the operating system informs SQLite that it is unable to perform some disk I/O operation. This could mean that there is no more space left on the disk.

Probably you should check for dealloc for every object that you allocated in your class.

As you said that when you run the app after quitting the app from background, it works fine.
This is because quitting the app deallocate all the memory occupied by your app.

Comment: No, the memory is not the issue. otherwise app will crash.

Comment: oh so you want to say if there would be any memory issue, the app will definitely crash. may be you are right swati but "SQLITE_IOERR" error comes only when there is a memory issue or a problem with hardware compatibility.